# Problems with updateExistingPivot

Tags: laravel

I have a pivot table with the relation of (sample_id, essay_id). In the same table I have the "result" field. The data I want to insert for each sample relationship with trial, I take it from an "input" called "result", from a form of a view.

The code in the controller is as follows:

```
public function uresultado(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Insert Results
    $sample = Sample::find($id);
    $essayIds = DB::table('essay_sample')->where('sample_id', $id)->get('essay_id');

    $results = Input::get('result');

    foreach( $sample->essays as $essay ) {
        $sample->essays()->updateExistingPivot(
            $essay->id,
            array('result'=>$results));
    }

}
```

And when I run I throw the following error:

"Array to string conversion"

I can't find a way to solve it, I've tried several ways, using "sync" too.
If someone can help me or guide me I will thank you, regards

Comment: What is in `$results`?

Comment: Hi Rwd, in "results" I bring data from a field that is in view. That's why I put this: $ results = Input :: get ('result');
The issue is that it is a collection of data since they correspond to the results of the "trials".
With the code I put in, it records the last data in the collection of the view ($ results = Input :: get ('result');), in all the 'result' fields of the bd. So if the collection is: results [21, 22, 23, 24], in the bd 'result' [24, 24, 24, 24]. I don't know why the function doesn't go through the array. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, the above is done with the following code:
  ** foreach ($ sample-> essays as $ essay) {foreach ($ results as $ result) {$ sample-> essays () -> updateExistingPivot ($ essay-> id, ['result' => $ result]) ; }} **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) shows that `updateExistingPivot($roleId, $attributes)` is a function that

> accepts the pivot record foreign key and an array of attributes to update

The `$attributes` parameter expects an associative (key-value) array with values to write to extra columns in the pivot table, such as `['column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2']`.

In your code you are entering an array into the array, and Eloquent fails trying to convert your `$results` array into a string value suitable for the one column `result`, hence the `Array to string conversion` error.

The solution depends on your goal. If you want to save `$result` as a comma-separated string into a single row, you could use `implode(',', [21, 22, 23, 24])`. In your code it would look like this:

```
$sample->essays()->updateExistingPivot(
    $essay->id,
    ['result' => implode(',', $results)]
);
```

Comment: I ended up solving the 2 arrays, within an "array []", since each data is associated with the other, so it was not useful to put them all in a single field with commas. Anyway, thank you very much, because I learned something new with your code. regards